# Splitting Image using OpenCV in python

Tags: python, opencv, python-2.7

I have an image and want to split it into three RGB channel images using CV2 in python.

I also want good documentation where I can find all the functions of openCV, as I am completely new to OpenCV.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

That is as simple as loading an image using `cv2.imread` and then use `cv2.split`:

```
>>> import cv2
>>> import numpy as np
>>> img = cv2.imread("foo.jpg")
>>> b,g,r = cv2.split(img)
```

OpenCV documentation is available from [docs.opencv.org](http://docs.opencv.org/)

Comment: How do i save those b,g,r images ? can you suggest me the documentation where i can find all the function?

Comment: If you want to save the blue channel: `cv2.imwrite('blue_channel.jpg', b)`

Comment: You could, just to be safe, use `cv2.imread("foo.jpg", 1)` to enforce loading into a 3-channel array

Comment: I ran the code of @jabaldonedo and got one image for R channel, one image for G channel and one image for B channel. When I open either R or G or B the result is black/white image. Is this normal?? I mean shouldn't there exist red, green, blue color inside the channel separated images??

Comment: If you plot each channel you will get a black and white image, that's normal. You need three channels to compose a color, with only one channel you can only plot black and white.

Answer (score 17):

As mentioned in the [documentation tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_core/py_basic_ops/py_basic_ops.html), the cv2.split() is a costly operation in terms of performance(time) **if you don't want to operate on all the channels but only one/two**, so the numpy indexing is preferred:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread("foo.jpg")
b = img[:,:,0]
g = img[:,:,1]
r = img[:,:,2]
```

Remember that opencv reads the images as BGR instead of RGB

**Edit:** @Mitch McMabers, Thanks for pointing this out. Please use this method for max efficiency if you want to work on just one/two channels separately. If you want to operate on all three channels, access the channels using cv2.split() as mentioned in @jabaldeno's answer.

Comment: You have misunderstood the documentation (the page you link to). It says: If you want to do something basic on 1 color channel (such as setting all red to zero), just use numpy indexing such as `img[:,:,2] = 0`, or you only want ONE of the three channels, use `b = img[:,:,0]`. In both those cases, it makes no sense to extract 3 channels. But if you DO want to get all 3 channels, it should be faster to use the split function.

Comment: @MitchMcMabers Actually, with my testing using `timeit` and a  `(1908, 2800, 3)` image, the indexing averaged `1.17 us` compared to split averaging `23.7 ms`. `cv2.split()` seems to be the costlier operation.

Comment: Hmm, interesting... `python -m timeit -s "import urllib.request as r; import cv2; from os.path import exists as ex; b='bench.jpg'; r.urlretrieve('https://i.imgur.com/7vGjNmZ.jpg',b) if not ex(b) else False; x=cv2.imread(b)" "b,g,r = cv2.split(x)"` gives `33.1 ms`, and `"b,g,r = x[:,:,0], x[:,:,1], x[:,:,2]"` gives `803 nsec (0.000803 ms)`. Weird! The latter with numpy indexing does 3 function calls to the numpy C extension, and the OpenCV method only does 1 C call and should be optimized, but it's not. Unless we're doing something wrong, this is good to know, thanks!

Comment: Nevermind, I've figured it out. The Numpy method uses Numpy slicing which makes a new (very inefficient) Numpy array "view" which points at the old RAM and says "read every 3rd byte, skip 1st and 2nd bytes" to only look at a single channel. This is "fake-splitting" the channels, but is EXTREMELY INEFFICIENT at image processing. EVERY time you pass fake r,g or b (created this way) to an OpenCV or other library function, you cause a 30 millisecond delay for each function call as it has to recreate the "cheating" Numpy data into a real image object. Meanwhile, the OpenCV split creates 3 real img.

Comment: Here is an article about the costs of cheating this way via Numpy. It may LOOK fast to use indexing ("ooh 0.000803 ms to split via numpy instead of 33.1ms to split via OpenCV"), but it's all a lie -- no data is split if you abuse the Numpy trick; no real "split" images are created in RAM -- and the Numpy trick is very, very slow in reality, because the data has to be fixed EVERY time you give such "fake splits" to OpenCV functions and other libraries: https://answers.opencv.org/question/219040/fastest-way-to-convert-bgr-rgb-aka-do-not-use-numpy-magic-tricks/ (`cv2.split()` is REAL splitting).

Comment: @MitchMcMabers, did you find any improvement using `.copy()` for each channel? (`b = img[:,:,0].copy()`, etc..)

Comment: @iGian Hi. Follow the earlier link to my opencv article. It covers that. The short answer: Creating copies of each channel guarantees that every channel is its own REAL, unique image in RAM which can be manipulated with zero delays. If you don't make a `.copy()`, then every function on the "fake channel images" will cause the same delay as a `.copy()` would have, but repeats the copy process EVERY time you call a function on that image. So yeah copying first is the best way if you need to reuse a channel image. BUT SINCE YOU NEED ALL 3 CHANNELS USE `b,g,r = cv2.split(img)` FOR MAX SPEED!

Comment: @MitchMcMabers Thank you for pointing this out. I've edited my answer. Feel free to edit if you want to add more clarity.