# Opencv imread with tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

i want to read photo into popup window via tkinter with opencv.How can i do it ?

```
def open_file():
    fln = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = os.getcwd(),title = "select file", filetypes =(("JPG File","*.jpg"),("PNG file","*.png"),("ALL files","*.*")))
    # img = Image.open(fln)
    # img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    # lbl.configure(image=img)
    # lbl.image = img
    blue,green,red = cv2.split(fln)
    img = cv2.merge((red,green,blue))
    im = Image.fromarray(img)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=im)
    lbl.configure(image = img)
    lbl.image = img
    button_show_image.destroy()
```

Comment: It looks like that you have tried to load the image into a tkinter `Label`, so what is your problem actually?

Comment: type error : m is not numpy array neither a scalar

Comment: The commented code works fine, why don't use it?

Comment: Does this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19181485/splitting-image-using-opencv-in-python) help?

Comment: yes this code used but new err: "    blue_ch = img[:,:,0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable"

Comment: Better create new question for new error.