# How can you store an image as a ndarray of each of its colour channels?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am currently trying to get an image and save it to an array of each of its colour channels (RGB). When I append the image to a list it instead stores the three colour channels of each pixel together. I was wondering how I could separate them?

Current code

```
img = cv2.imread(f'Data/keyboard/00{i+1:02d}.jpg') 
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)   # BGR -> RGB  
imgdata.append([img,"keyboard"])

print(trainData[0][0][0])
```

Current output

```
 [185, 233, 255]
 [185, 233, 255]
 [185, 233, 255]
 ...
 [189 229 254]
```

Needed Format

```
Red = [[185,185,16,...,189],[185,185,16,...,185],...]
Green = [[233,233,233,...,229],[233,233,233,...,229],...]
Blue = [[255,255,255,...,254],[255,255,255,...,254],...]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Splitting Image using OpenCV in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19181485/splitting-image-using-opencv-in-python)

Comment: ` R, G, B = cv2.split(img)` gives you 3 2D arrays each containing the respective channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you load in your image using `cv2` and perform the color conversion, you can verify its dimensions using `img.shape` which will be in the form of W, H, 3, where 3 represents the R, G, and B color channels.

Now to separate the colors, you can start by reshaping the image data to 2 dimensions as `(W*H, 3)` using the following code

```py
w, h, channels = img.shape
img_reshaped = img.reshape((w * h, channels))
```

This way each entry will be `[R, G, B]`. However, to extract just the `R`, `G`, or `B`, you would use an second dimension index of 0, 1, or 2 respectively. 
For example, to extract all the red values, you would use
`reds = img_reshaped[:, 0]`

If you need to extend this to multiple images, you could call the `extend()` function or use a NumPy array initialized to the right size using `np.zeros()`

Comment: the reshape may not be necessary. OP's question is unclear on that IMHO. if this is input to a neural network, flattening the data makes no sense. -- `extend` on numpy arrays always implies a copy. best not to do that if this is executed in a loop. the identifier `trainData` implies that this will be applied to multiple images.

Answer (score 1):

- Don't `cvtColor`. Not necessary, hence useless.
- Don't reshape to `(w*h, channels)`. Not necessary, hence useless.

Even `cv.split` isn't strictly necessary because it's (nearly) equivalent to numpy slicing. Numpy slicing creates views, while `cv.split` creates copies. Creating copies may not be useful here.

```
# given:
#img = cv2.imread(f'Data/keyboard/00{i+1:02d}.jpg')
# order is BGR

red = img[:,:,2]
green = img[:,:,1]
blue = img[:,:,0]
```

These are **slices**, a numpy thing. You can now do with them whatever you like, such as appending to a list.

```
reds = []
greens = []
blues = []

for img in images:
    reds.append(img[:,:,2])
    greens.append(img[:,:,1])
    blues.append(img[:,:,0])

reds = np.array(reds)
greens = np.array(greens)
blues = np.array(blues)
```

If you *need to* flatten these arrays, you can do that. You generally don't need to. What you need depends on what you're gonna do with it. You haven't explained that.